# how to examin white quads in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a small chessboard and I put a geometric objects in the white squares, now I'm trying to extract  them from the image using cv::findContours(), here my code and the source and result images:

```
int main (){
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("quad.jpg",0);
    cv::Mat image ;
    cv::Mat result(img.size(),CV_8U,cv::Scalar(255));
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
    //std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> hiararchy;
    cv::threshold(img,img,127,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    cv::findContours(img,contours,/*hiararchy,*/CV_RETR_TREE    , CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE );
-1, // draw all contours
cv::Scalar(0), // in black
2); // with a thickness of 2
    cv::imshow("result",result);
    //cv::imwrite("con.jpg",result);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
```

source

[image: source]

result

[image: result]

any idea how  to tell the program : care only about the white squares

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [hough transform](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) to find the longest lines in the image. This will give you the grid of the checkerboard. Next you can check the average pixel colour within each "cell" on the grid to determine whether it's a black or a white square.

Comment: thanks for your answer , but how can I do the second part, checking the average pixel color, and "talking" with **each** cell

Comment: Once you have the lines, group them into roughly horizontal and roughly vertical lines using their slopes. You can then find the points of intersection on the image, which then gives you the corners of the cells. For example, you can get the corners of the top left cell by finding the points of intersection of the two top-most horizontal and the two left-most vertical lines.